# Using Pivot or UnPivot to get Output Dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with the following structure that I want to receive output from this table dynamically. But I do not know how to use Pivot and UnPivot.

The list of fields I use is as follows.

```
    SELECT [RoomID]
          ,[RoomNumber]
          ,[RoomType]
          ,[RoomTypeDescription]
          ,[RoomBed]
          ,[PriceOfPerNight]
          ,[RoomStatuse]
          ,[RoomStatuseDesc]
          ,[RoomFloorID]
          ,[RoomFloorTitle]
      FROM [HotelOnline].[dbo].[XtblRooms]


    RoomID  RoomNumber  RType   RDesc       Beds    Price       RoomStatuse RDesc   FloorID RoomFloorTitle
    1   RM100001    2   Degree 2    6   9000000.00  1   Free    1   Floor 001
    2   RM100002    1   Degree 1    4   6000000.00  1   Free    1   Floor 001
    3   RM100003    2   Degree 2    3   4500000.00  1   Free    1   Floor 001
    4   RM100004    3   Degree 3    5   4800000.00  1   Free    1   Floor 001
    5   RM100005    1   Degree 1    3   4700000.00  1   Free    1   Floor 001
    6   RM100006    1   Degree 1    6   7500000.00  1   Free    1   Floor 001
    7   RM100007    1   Degree 1    5   7000000.00  1   Free    1   Floor 001
    8   RM100008    1   Degree 1    2   2500000.00  1   Free    1   Floor 001
    9   RM100009    3   Degree 3    3   3500000.00  1   Free    1   Floor 001
    10  RM100010    3   Degree 3    8   8000000.00  1   Free    1   Floor 001
    11  RM100011    2   Degree 2    5   6500000.00  1   Free    2   Floor 002
    12  RM100012    3   Degree 3    2   3800000.00  1   Free    2   Floor 002
    13  RM100013    2   Degree 2    5   9650000.00  1   Free    2   Floor 002
    14  RM100014    3   Degree 3    2   2500000.00  1   Free    2   Floor 002
    15  RM100015    2   Degree 2    2   4500000.00  1   Free    2   Floor 002
    16  RM100016    3   Degree 3    4   4000000.00  1   Free    2   Floor 002
    17  RM100017    1   Degree 1    2   2500000.00  1   Free    2   Floor 002
    18  RM100018    3   Degree 3    3   4500000.00  1   Free    2   Floor 002
    19  RM100019    2   Degree 2    5   5000000.00  1   Free    2   Floor 002
    20  RM100020    2   Degree 2    4   4500000.00  1   Free    2   Floor 002
    21  RM100021    1   Degree 1    6   7500000.00  1   Free    3   Floor 003
    22  RM100022    2   Degree 2    3   3000000.00  1   Free    3   Floor 003
    23  RM100023    3   Degree 3    3   2500000.00  1   Free    3   Floor 003
    24  RM100024    1   Degree 1    3   2500000.00  1   Free    3   Floor 003
    25  RM100025    2   Degree 2    5   4800000.00  1   Free    3   Floor 003
    26  RM100026    3   Degree 3    4   4000000.00  1   Free    3   Floor 003
    27  RM100027    2   Degree 2    2   1800000.00  1   Free    3   Floor 003
    28  RM100028    3   Degree 3    5   4700000.00  1   Free    3   Floor 003
    29  RM100029    1   Degree 1    3   3500000.00  1   Free    3   Floor 003
    30  RM100030    2   Degree 2    6   4600000.00  1   Free    3   Floor 003
    31  RM100031    2   Degree 2    5   4500000.00  1   Free    4   Floor 004
    32  RM100032    1   Degree 1    2   3500000.00  1   Free    4   Floor 004
    33  RM100033    3   Degree 3    4   3700000.00  1   Free    4   Floor 004
    34  RM100034    2   Degree 2    3   2800000.00  1   Free    4   Floor 004
    35  RM100035    3   Degree 3    6   5500000.00  1   Free    4   Floor 004
    36  RM100036    2   Degree 2    4   3700000.00  1   Free    4   Floor 004
    37  RM100037    3   Degree 3    6   5800000.00  1   Free    4   Floor 004
    38  RM100038    1   Degree 1    3   4000000.00  1   Free    4   Floor 004
    39  RM100039    1   Degree 1    5   5500000.00  1   Free    4   Floor 004
    40  RM100040    1   Degree 1    6   6500000.00  1   Free    4   Floor 004
    41  RM100041    1   Degree 1    4   4500000.00  1   Free    5   Floor 005
    42  RM100042    2   Degree 2    6   5500000.00  1   Free    5   Floor 005
    43  RM100043    2   Degree 2    4   4000000.00  1   Free    5   Floor 005
    44  RM100044    2   Degree 2    3   3500000.00  1   Free    5   Floor 005
    45  RM100045    3   Degree 3    3   3000000.00  1   Free    5   Floor 005
    46  RM100046    3   Degree 3    5   4000000.00  1   Free    5   Floor 005
    47  RM100047    3   Degree 3    4   3900000.00  1   Free    5   Floor 005
    48  RM100048    2   Degree 2    5   4700000.00  1   Free    5   Floor 005
    49  RM100049    2   Degree 2    3   3800000.00  1   Free    5   Floor 005
    50  RM100050    3   Degree 3    5   4700000.00  1   Free    5   Floor 005
```

**This is the output I need.**

```
    Floor 001   Floor 002   Floor 003   Floor 004   Floor 005
    ==========================================================
    RM100001    RM100012    RM100028    RM100033    RM100049
    RM100002    RM100013    RM100029    RM100033    RM100050
    .. . . . . .
```

I tried several ways but did not get the answer. Help if possible. I tried several ways but did not get the answer. Help if possible. If possible, use the dynamic method to get the answer. It does not matter if it is not for you. My problem will be solved in the same way as usual.

Comment: PLleas look at "This is the output I need." Before write anything else. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to help me, please do the method mentioned in the query I sent. thanks. @Larnu

Comment: SELECT [RoomID]
          ,[RoomNumber]
          ,[RoomType]
          ,[RoomTypeDescription]
          ,[RoomBed]
          ,[PriceOfPerNight]
          ,[RoomStatuse]
          ,[RoomStatuseDesc]
          ,[RoomFloorID]
          ,[RoomFloorTitle]
      FROM [HotelOnline].[dbo].[XtblRooms]    @Larnu

Comment: you say"  It does not matter if it is not for you. My problem will be solved in the same way as usual." What does this mean "the same way as usual"?

You ask for a dynamic query....is this because you do not know in advance the number of floors?  WHat is the maximum number of floors that is possible?

Comment: ***You*** asked the question about *your* work, @AliNajafZadeh , you have asked us to interfere... If you don't want answers (which linked duplicates count as) don't post questions.

Answer (score 1):

Because I am "illiterate" I was unable to answer this question:

```sql
--If you want a full working example for your data, provide full DDL and DML statements.
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
    ('1','RM100001','2','Degree 2','6','9000000.00','1','Free','1','Floor 001'),
    ('2','RM100002','1','Degree 1','4','6000000.00','1','Free','1','Floor 001'),
    ('3','RM100003','2','Degree 2','3','4500000.00','1','Free','1','Floor 001'),
    ('4','RM100004','3','Degree 3','5','4800000.00','1','Free','1','Floor 001'),
    ('5','RM100005','1','Degree 1','3','4700000.00','1','Free','1','Floor 001'),
    ('6','RM100006','1','Degree 1','6','7500000.00','1','Free','1','Floor 001'),
    ('7','RM100007','1','Degree 1','5','7000000.00','1','Free','1','Floor 001'),
    ('8','RM100008','1','Degree 1','2','2500000.00','1','Free','1','Floor 001'),
    ('9','RM100009','3','Degree 3','3','3500000.00','1','Free','1','Floor 001'),
    ('10','RM100010','3','Degree 3','8','8000000.00','1','Free','1','Floor 001'),
    ('11','RM100011','2','Degree 2','5','6500000.00','1','Free','2','Floor 002'))V(RoomID,RoomNumber,RType,RDesc,Beds,Price,RoomStatuse,RDesc2,FloorID,RoomFloorTitle)),
/*
Having multiple columns with the same name is a design flaw (not allowed).
I have named the second Rdesc as RDesc2, but this is also flawed (it breaks normalisation rules).
Fix your design, normalise your data.
*/
RNs AS(
    SELECT RoomNumber,
           RoomFloorTitle,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RoomFloorTitle ORDER BY RoomNumber) AS RN --ORDER BY should be your ID/always ascending column
    FROM YourTable)
SELECT MAX(CASE RoomFloorTitle WHEN 'Floor 001' THEN RoomNumber END) AS Floor001,
       MAX(CASE RoomFloorTitle WHEN 'Floor 002' THEN RoomNumber END) AS Floor002
FROM RNs
GROUP BY RN;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=26a092d059bac004e156f939ab2d4c92)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *   
FROM (
      select  RoomStatuseDesc, 
              RoomNumber, 
              count(*) over (partition by RoomStatuseDesc order by 
                             RoomNumber) rm2  from XtblRooms)as XtblRooms 
PIVOT (max(RoomNumber) --as R_count, min(RoomNumber) as r_start
       for RoomStatuseDesc in('Floor1','Floor2', 'Floor3', 'Floor4', 'Floor5'))pvt
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).